# Regular expressions to match the version number and month index

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I want to match a string that contains year month index i.e, 202011 and version number after V i.e, V1.
String examples are ABCD.202011.V2.txt , QWERTY.201120.V1.csv

I tried `(?:\b|\s|^)(\d{6})(?=[.?\s]|\b|$)` for 6 digit number. It doesnot seem to work in python.

I want to incorporate one single regex to get both month index as well as version.

Comment: Why `d{4}` if you're trying to match 6 digits?

Comment: I changed it. That was a mistake while copying.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `re.findall`:

```py
inp = "String examples are ABCD.202011.V2.txt , QWERTY.201120.V1.csv"
matches = re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+\.(\d{6})\.V(\d+)\.\w+\b', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
[('202011', '2'), ('201120', '1')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use 3 capturing groups if you want the year as 4 digits, month index as 2 digits and version as 1 or more digits.

```
\b[A-Z]+\.(\d{4})(\d{2})\.V(\d+)\.\w+
```

- `\b[A-Z]+\.` A word boundary, match 1+ uppercase chars
- `(\d{4})` Capture **group 1**, match 4 digits
- `(\d{2})` Capture **group 2**, match 2 digits
- `\.V` Match `.V`
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 3**, match 1+ digit
- `\.\w+` Match a `.` and 1+ word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nrpWCX/1)